# PHP library for automatically mirroring webpages?

Tags: software-development, library

I'm wanting to accomplish something like using `wget --mirror --convert-links` (I.e., makes a local copy of a website and change any local links to relative paths; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145641/wget-how-to-mirror-only-a-section-of-a-website), but using pure PHP so I can distribute it with my WordPress plugin and it'll work on systems that might not necessarily have `wget`.

Anyone know of anything like that?